# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split').,

Tags: javascript

why am i getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
> in:

```js
targetign=process.argv[2]
login=process.argv[3];
proxy=process.argv[4];
proxysplit=proxy.split(":");
loginsplit=login.split(":")
```

i want to split proxy and login

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass them as arguments after the file name, and access them using the correct indexes. like this:

```
node index.js targetign login:password proxy:host:port
```

Then

```
let targetign = process.argv[2];
let login = process.argv[3];
let proxy = process.argv[4];
let proxysplit = proxy.split(":");
let loginsplit = login.split(":");
```